# 4 bit by 8 bit Assembly Multiplication

Tags: assembly, multiplication

I am having a problem displaying the four digits on a seven segment display.  I have the following loop and everything works well excepting the display in the MSB.  I know this is because the input S9 is only 4 bits, so when I multiply it by SA(which is the current value of the seven segment display) the result only gives me 12 bits and the last digit remains at 0 even when I keep multiplying where the other digits overflow to the next.  So I don't know how to make it a four digit without altering the product.  See an example below with results in the display. 
F times F gives me 00E1
E1 times F gives me 0D2F
D2F times F gives me 02C1 (Where there should already be a digit in the MSB)

My code is below:

```
        LOAD SB, 00
        LOAD SF, 08

        multloop:
        SR0 SA;

        JUMP NC, shiftproduct 

        ADD SB, s9 

        shiftproduct :
        SRA SB
        SRA SC 

        SUB SF, 01
        JUMP NZ, multloop

        OUTPUT sB,05 ; upper byte of seven segment display
        OUTPUT sC,04 ; lower byte of seven segment display
```

Thank you,
Julius

Comment: Not sure what CPU this is for, or whether it's just conceptual, but does `SRA` rotate through the carry? Also (this is not the cause of your problem), you probably should have `LOAD SC, 00` at the beginning. As an efficiency, you can terminate your loop when `SA` becomes zero. You don't need a loop counter in `SF`. If you have an "add with carry" instruction, I would use the 4-bit number as the multiplier instead of the 8 bit number, which would potentially be half the number of loop iterations.

Comment: I think your loop is also going to do the shift left of the product too many times by the time it's done. According to your loop logic, the `SRA SB` and `SRA SC` are done right before you decide whether to exit the loop. If that's the case, you would always see an even product (even though in your statement, you're saying you're getting correct results). You probably want to do the shift *after* deciding whether to exit the loop before you go around again.

Comment: Hi Lurker, thank you for your response.  Yes SRA rotates through all bits including carry.

Comment: Regarding LOAD SC, 00, that is my problem, SC is a 4 bit input defined by 4 slider switches on my fpga board. I attempted changing the loop order with no luck, but thank you for taking the time to help me out.

Comment: Also, did you mean changing S9 by SA? SA is my 4 bit input. I just gave that a try as well.

Comment: Ah OK sorry, I didn't realize some of those were hardware ports.

Answer (score 0):

I would rework the code this way. The issues with the old version are:

- The `SC` register hasn't been initialized to `00` (maybe it was 00 to start, but I didn't want to assume it was)
- When adding the multiplicand to the product `SC:SB`, you not only need to add it to `SB`, but you need to add any resulting carry to `SC`

  ```
      LOAD    SB, 00
      LOAD    SC, 00            ; <-- Needed to init SC
      LOAD    SF, 08            ; Loop counter

  multloop:
      SR0     SA
      JUMP    NC, shiftproduct 

      ADD     SB, s9
      ADDCY   SC, 00            ; <-- NEEDED and add C here to SC

  shiftproduct:
      SRA     SB
      SRA     SC 

      SUB     SF, 01
      JUMP    NZ, multloop

      OUTPUT  sB,05             ; upper byte of seven segment display
      OUTPUT  sC,04             ; lower byte of seven segment display
  ```

Comment: @Julius I just realized I had something wrong in the implementation. Please see my updated answer. Your implementation was closer to correct than I thought, as I didn't realize it was sort of running the standard multiply routine in reverse. And so the loop counter is needed.

Comment: I found my problem, I needed to multiply again by the second byte and add the response to the hundreds of the first byte. Thanks for your help.